# Filter out specific String using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Input :

```
<img xlink:href="figure_one"><?isoimg-id 9324-098_kr1figure1.JPG?></img>
```

I want to filter out as `.jpg` part from above input using XSLT. I have no idea to how can I filter out it.

Comment: XML is case-sensitive; there is no `.jpg` part in your input. Also "filter out" is a rather ambiguous expression.

Comment: I want to convert to lower case too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply remove the file extension (regardless of what it is) by using the `substring-before()` function:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('isoimg-id')">
    <xsl:processing-instruction  name="isoimg-id">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')" />
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That depends on whether your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or not.

Comment: Please post this as a new question, as the answer will be radically different.

Comment: I suggest you post a new one and leave this one as it is - it may help someone else.